# How to get directory list of a folder with subfolders that are longer than 260 chars

Tags: batch-file, cmd, directory, size

This is the code that I am using to generate the size of a folder

```
for /f "tokens=3,5" %%a in ('
    dir /a /s /w /-c "%target%"
    ^| findstr /b /l /c:"  "
    ') do if "%%b"=="" set "size=%%a"
echo %size%
```

I am running into an issue where for some of the folders, there are too many subfolders, and it spits out "The directory name "K:\Really\Long\Path\Blah" is too long" (not the actual dir- the actual dir is longer than 260 chars). Because of this, it never gets the size of that folder, and my size is not correct.

Comment: You could try it the PowerShell way.  (Don't worry.  You can still put this in a .bat script.)  `for /f "usebackq" %%a in (\`powershell "gci -r -path '%target%' ^| %%{ $s += $_.length }; '{0:N0}' -f $s"\`) do set "size=%%a"`

Comment: nope, still get "gci : The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260
characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters."

Comment: How about `for /f "usebackq" %%a in (\`powershell "gci -r -path '%target%' ^| measure -s length ^| %%{ '{0:N0}' -f $_.sum }"\`) do set "res=%%a"` ?

Comment: for /f "usebackq" %%a in (`powershell "gci -r -path 'K:\AA\Test aaaa Aaaaaaaaaa\AAAA A\aa-AAAA\Long\Loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo' | measure -s length ^| %%{ '{0:N0}' -f $_.sum }"`) do echo %%a ---> this gave me the last output as '+' - I didn't see any other relevant information being output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer might not help everyone but for what I was using it for it sufficed. I used robocopy to get the size, since it doesn't actually iterate through (?) and gave me the correct size including those folders with too long pathnames (doesnt help if your full_path is too long to start with)

```
for /f "tokens=1-10,* delims= " %%a in ('
call robocopy "!full_path!" %TEMP% /S /L /BYTES /XJ /NFL /NDL /NJH ^| find "Bytes"') do (
    echo !full_path!: %%c
    set totalsize=%%c
)
```